# How is junction-to-ambient temperature measured?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, diodes, heat, thermal

Is the test done is still air (natural convection)?
If I know junction-to-ambient resistance and max junction temperature, can I use it to directly derive heat loss?
P=(Tjmax-Tamb)/Rja

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless otherwise specified in the datasheet it is measured in still air.  The value also typically has a lot of other assumptions.

For example for surface mount components there may be a spec for the size and weight of the copper pad(s). Those assumptions may not be valid for your layout, so you have to plan accordingly.

If your component is isolated from other heat-generating sources or components, and you have roughly the same layout and conditions as the datasheet spec, you should be able to get a rough estimate of the power dissipation from the junction temperature (and ambient temp).  It may not be very accurate.

Answer (score 0):

> If I know junction-to-ambient resistance and max junction temperature, can I use it to directly derive heat loss?

Given you know the max junction temperature \$T_J\$, the ambient temperature where the IC is housed \$T_A\$and the junction-to-ambient thermal resistance \$R_{JA}\$, you can *estimate* the maximum power through the junction using

\$P=({T_J-T_A})/R_{JA}\$

This would be a rough estimate of the heat loss. However, there are many other considerations needed to get a more accurate result. For example, the PCB board type the IC is mounted on, can change the \$R_{JA}\$ value by as much as 50% according to this [Texas Instruments Report](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra953c/spra953c.pdf?ts=1655542660791#:%7E:text=Many%20thermal%20metrics%20exist%20for,junction%20temperatures%20in%20their%20systems.). Here is a plot from that article showing the difference between 1s (one signal layer) and 2s2p (two signal layers/two power layers)
[image]

> Is the test done is still air (natural convection)?

This is up to the person doing the test. Do you want to know how the IC performs in a vacuum? What about in stagnant, humid air? If the IC is going to live on a PCB inside an unventilated enclosure, that would be a good environment to test the IC in.